# How to add Facebook 'Like' button to CiviCRM mailings

Tags: facebook, drupal, facebook-like, civicrm

I'm trying to add the facebook 'Like' button to my CiviCRM civiMail footer template.
When I paste the downloaded code into the footer code the CiviCRM editor flags up the following error
"Illegal characters in input (potential scripting attack)"

(I have pasted the code into my HTML pages and added to my Wordpress pages and it works fine in both but wont work in CiviMail)

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't embed script code into HTML emails.  At least you can't and expect it to run.  The best you can do is embed some kind of fake like button that is a simple image and hyperlink to your fan page or the url that you want people to like which will open in their browser and then they could like it from there.